# How to send a notification to an Android App that the User has manually changed the Volume Control Keys?

Tags: android, development-environment

I am trying to work out a solution here. I am currently developing an App that streams live recordings.  If the User manually changes the Volume Control Keys, I would like this change to notify the App and reflect/update this change on the Virtual Volume Slider Bar in the App?

Comment: so like looking for a volume onClick() then getting the volume % and changing the on-screen volume bar to that?

Answer (score 1):

I would probobally do this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
{  
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {  
       //get the cur volume, set your on screen to this volume
   } else { 
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);  
   } 
}
```